# Efficient way to make container take remaining width in a Row widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and was practicing its UI where I came across a situation where I had a list where each list element have an image on the left and some text on right.

Below is my approach to that

```
child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Row(
              children: [
                 Container(
                        height: 80,
                        width: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          image: const DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage('http://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555010133-d883506aedee?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=1080&fit=max'),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover
                          )
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        height: 80,
                        width: 280,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Here I am specifying width individually for both containers which is not an efficient way to do this since phone sizes may vary.
Below is the result for above block of code

[Screenshot of the app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqumI.png)

I tried specifying crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch to the Row() but it throws an error as below

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
```

How can I achieve this? Please assist

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the widget with an [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) inside the row:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    ...otherChildren,
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        height: 80,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: they are now taking up equal space, how do i set them to take specified spaces?

Comment: only wrap the green container with `Expanded`, leave the photo as is.

Comment: yes it worked but i am still using width no the picture container, can it be something like CSS flex where i specify like 30% for picture and remaining area for green container

Comment: Yes, you can. `Expanded` has a property called `flex`. Wrap both with `Expanded`. Now you can set the `flex` of the photo to 3 and the `flex` of the green container to `7` to achieve the 30%/70% split you desire.

Comment: BINGO, it worked, thanks a lot I'll mark it as an answer soon. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView.builder` with `ListTile` widgets. It has a leading widget (normally an icon or an avatar) to the left, text in the middle and trailing widget (normally an icon), each of which is optional.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: ...,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: const CircleAvatar(
        radius: 20.0,
        foregroundImage: NetworkImage(...),
      ),
      title: Text(...),
      subtitle: Text(...),
      trailing: ...,
      onTap: () => ...,
    );
  },
)
```